# Angular preview Image in correct place

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to select some images and view them in various places.

I can select the images, but how can I put them in different places?

I have several boxes, if I select 3 images, I would like one to be in the main box (big box) and the remaining two to be placed in the smaller ones.

Can anyone help me?

[StackBlitz ----> see my code here pls](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfnkee)

```
urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    this.urls = [];
    let files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
      for (let file of files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Html**

```
  <img *ngFor="let url of urls" [src]="url" width="300" height="300" id="list">
  <input type="file" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">
<div class="row">
    <div class="Upcard">
      <div class="card-block" id="2">
      </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="Upcard">
      <div class="card-block" id="3">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: StackBlitz links are helpful, but please include relevant broken code in the question as well.

Comment: sorry, 
I already add the code

Comment: "...please include relevant broken code in the question as well." meaning it should be in your post, not just a link.

Comment: No, I was already adding in the post, I don't understand why they denied me soon

Comment: You can place the *ngFor on the .Upcard div and simply render the image here in .card-block.

Comment: @thinkwinwin I didn't understand very well, can you help me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<!-- render first image here -->
<img [src]="urls[0]" width="300" height="300" id="list">
<input type="file" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">
<div class="row">
    <!-- Render items except the first here: -->
    <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls | slice:1">
      <div class="card-block">
          <img [src]="url" width="300" height="300">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You always render the first item in `urls` at the top, and the rest (except the first item) down below in the ngFor.

Comment: Perfect !!! now how can i put an image 1 (big box) taking up all the space? is that at this moment only appears in a square :(